# How to hide "More from" section of Facebook Instant Article

Tags: facebook-page, facebook-instant-articles

Is that possible to hide "More from" section at the end of Facebook Instant Article?

I have read the format reference that only mentioned how to show but there is no clue on hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply remove the related article section from the article footer markup. You can see an example in [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/guides/articlecreate#sample-article)

```
  <!-- Analytics code for your article -->
  <figure class="op-tracker">
      <iframe src="" hidden></iframe>
  </figure>
  <footer>
    <!-- Credits for your article -->
    <aside>Acknowledgements</aside>
    <!-- Copyright details for your article -->
    <small>Legal notes</small>
  </footer>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to hide that section but you have the option to provide the list of related articles yourself by using the op-related class - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/related-articles.